# has_one relationship validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations

Since `has_one` doesn't provide a `before_add` callback to allow validation,
how do I prevent rails from destroying the old association even when the
new one does'nt pass validation?

susan :has_one :shirt
shirt :belongs_to :susan

susan.shirt = a_nice_shirt

this destroys whatever association was present beforehand,
even if the new shirt is never realy associated because it didn't pass
validation, leaving a shirtless susan behind (well, acutally leaving a shirt
behind that doesn't belong to anyone..).

```
susan.build_shirt
```

does the same thing

Is there a good reason for the missing `before_add` callback that I overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why that callback isn't there, but you can always just add an Observer to the model, and verify the new association in a before_save.  I'll assume "susan" is a User Model instance, and the shirt has to be red to pass validation.

```
class UserObserver< ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_save(user)
    return false if user.shirt.color != "red"
  end
end
```

If you return false in the observer, the object won't save.  Of course, your current instance of "susan" will still have the invalid association.  I'm not positive, but if you change the before_save_ in the observer to something like this:

```
class UserObserver< ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_save(user)
    if user.shirt.color != "red"
      user.reload
      false
  end
end
```

Might refresh the instance of your User.  I've never tried this though.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails validation is usually done when you try to save the object to the database (using `save` or `save!`), not when it's modified. If for any reason you would like to restore the old value when the validation fails you can either `reload` the object or use the new [dirty attributes feature](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this ticket:

http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/10518

It appears that the functionality described there is still present if you have :dependent => :destroy on your association.

Personally, I think this is a bug in rails.